# google maps api v3 how to rank by closest distance

Tags: google-maps, search, rank

Does anyone know how to use the rank by distance search option that is mentioned here?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Listing this in the request options doesn't seem to work. Here's my portion of code relative to this:

```
var request = {
  location: coords,
  //radius: 30000,
  keyword: ['puma, retail'],
  types: ['store'],
  rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
                            listResults(results[i]);
        }
    } 
}
```

Code will locate and list results if I include a radius, but the results aren't listed in ascending order by distance. Google's docs say a radius isn't necessary either if using the rankBy option. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm in the same boat... hunting for a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was having the same problem.
 As per this source:  http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_place-search.html
 I was able to formulate the query as such:

```
var request = {
location: gps,
types: ['food'], //You can substitute "keyword: 'food'," (without double-quotes) here as well.
rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE, //Note there is no quotes here, I made that mistake.
key: key 
};
```

Var key is API key which is not required but added for later use.  GPS is:

```
var gps = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat,location.lon);
```

Lastly, I did everything that you did except I added bounds to a map that I was not going to use.  For that I did:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Comment: 'types' should be 'type' if you want to replace the value with a variable. Otherwise, it will not work.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot use radius and RankBy.DISTANCE properties together. Therefore you have two options:

1) Search by radius then sort the results by distance in your own code.

Example:

```
var request = {
               location: coords,
               radius: 30000,
               keyword: ['puma, retail'],
               types: ['store']
               };
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
           sortresults(results[i]);//sortresult uses haversine to calcuate distance and then arranges the result in the order of distance
           createMarker(results[i]);
           listResults(results[i]);
       }
   } 
}
```

Option 2: Search by RankBy.Distance then cap the result using the radius. Again you would need haversine formula to calculate distances.

```
var request = {
               location: coords,
               rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
               keyword: ['puma, retail'],
               types: ['store']
               };
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

           for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
           d= distance(coords,results[i].latlng)
           if(d<rd)
            {createMarker(results[i]);
             listResults(results[i]);
            }
           }
   } 
}

//Returns Distance between two latlng objects using haversine formula
distance(p1, p2) {
 if (!p1 || !p2) 
  return 0;
 var R = 6371000; // Radius of the Earth in m
 var dLat = (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * Math.PI / 180;
 var dLon = (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * Math.PI / 180;
 var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
 Math.cos(p1.lat() * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(p2.lat() * Math.PI / 180) *
 Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
 var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
 var d = R * c;
 return d;
 }
```

Comment: This was definitely the correct answer for me, I experienced the same problem as @JFlo

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use radius + rankBy properties together.

If you need the closest locations, choose some types, and set the rankBy proprety.

```
places.nearbySearch({
                        location: LatLng,
                        types: placeTypes,
                        rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
                    },
                    function (results) {
                        // process the results, r[0] is the closest place
                    }
                );
```

where you can set placeTypes like this

```
var placeTypes = [
'accounting',
'airport',
'amusement_park',
'aquarium',
'art_gallery',
'atm',
'bakery',
'bank',
'bar',
'beauty_salon',
'bicycle_store',
'book_store',
'bowling_alley',
'bus_station',
'cafe',
'campground',
'car_dealer',
'car_rental',
'car_repair',
'car_wash',
'casino',
'cemetery',
'church',
'city_hall',
'clothing_store',
'convenience_store',
'courthouse',
'dentist',
'department_store',
'doctor',
'electrician',
'electronics_store',
'embassy',
'establishment',
'finance',
'fire_station',
'florist',
'food',
'funeral_home',
'furniture_store',
'gas_station',
'general_contractor',
'grocery_or_supermarket',
'gym',
'hair_care',
'hardware_store',
'health',
'hindu_temple',
'home_goods_store',
'hospital',
'insurance_agency',
'jewelry_store',
'laundry',
'lawyer',
'library',
'liquor_store',
'local_government_office',
'locksmith',
'lodging',
'meal_delivery',
'meal_takeaway',
'mosque',
'movie_rental',
'movie_theater',
'moving_company',
'museum',
'night_club',
'painter',
'park',
'parking',
'pet_store',
'pharmacy',
'physiotherapist',
'place_of_worship',
'plumber',
'police',
'post_office',
'real_estate_agency',
'restaurant',
'roofing_contractor',
'rv_park',
'school',
'shoe_store',
'shopping_mall',
'spa',
'stadium',
'storage',
'store',
'subway_station',
'synagogue',
'taxi_stand',
'train_station',
'travel_agency',
'university',
'veterinary_care',
'zoo'
```

];

Answer (score 1):

Please note that on the current Api Doc the "search" method on the PlacesService class **is not available**.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=it#PlacesService

You have to choose betwen:

- nearbySearch (retrieve 20 result per page, max 3 pages)
- radarSearch (retrieve 200 result but with less details)
- textSearch (similar to the nearbySearch)

**If you choose to RankBy.DISTANCE you cant set the radius**

```
var request = {
  location: vLatLng,
  //radius: vRaggio,
  rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
  keyword: ['puma, retail'],
  types: ['store']
}

placesService.nearbySearch(request, function (data, status, placeSearchPagination) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  //...
  // do your stuffs with data results
  //...
  if (placeSearchPagination && placeSearchPagination.hasNextPage) {
    placeSearchPagination.nextPage();
  } 
});
```

If you want to restrict data based on a distance radius you can use this function to check if the resut is too far.

```
function checkRadiusDistance(place,centerLatLng,radius) {
  return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(place.geometry.location, centerLatLng) < radius;
});
```

Please note that this is also the only way to **obtain places inside a certain radius** beacuse when you specify "*rankBy:google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE*" and a "*radius=xx*" the placesService give you **also results outside the defined area**.