# How can I get the name of the closest gas station printed out using Google Places API for javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-places

I'm pretty new to Javascript, but I want to create a simple app. It must show the name of the closest gas station when a button is clicked. It also must print it using `document.write()`.

I have been looking at the documentation that Google has provided and I am confused about how to use `rankBy.DISTANCE` routine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the longitude and latitude of your location through javascript. According to it check whether is there any gas station available within your preferred area. You can get the javascript api from [Link is here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

To use rank by closest distance [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726533/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-rank-by-closest-distance)